# How can I bring down the pH of corrosive substance leaving its physical properties intact?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ph

I am developing geopolymers with kaolinite clay and calcium hydroxide activated with sodium carbonate solution. The alkalinity of the mix is too high to handle.. what can I do to bring it down?

Comment: Try neutralizing part or all of the Ca(OH)2 (with CO2), and employ more of the mildly alkaline Na2CO3.

Comment: Geopolymers are synthesized at very high pH. You are not supposed to use glassware. What is it corroding??

Comment: It is Na2CO3 that turns into caustic soda when mixed with water which makes it corrosive.. Also i believe the silicates in the kaolinite also turns caustic at when mixed to this.. i want to make it a material which can be handled by workers.. hence i need to bring the pH to less than 12 i guess..

Comment: Add sodium bicarbonate. The pH will soon go down under 9.

Comment: When creating sodium hydroxide from sodium carbonate, I would not wonder why it is so much alkaline.